# Python - Difference between getting a value in dictionary using those two methods

Tags: python, dictionary, enumerate

I'm beginner in Python, and making a words game. And have a dictionary of `{"player 1":0, "player 2":0}` that keeps track of the two players score.

I have a play again option so i need to always store the score into that dictionary.

But when i retrieve this dictionary values after each round using this :

```
for value, index in enumerate(players):
      print index, " : ", value
```

I get this just no matter how many rounds are played :

```
Player 2 : 0
Player 1 : 1
```

But when i use :

```
for index in players:
     print index, " : ", players.get(index, 0)
```

I get the actual values that i want.

My question is what's the difference between getting values using the two methods ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`enumerate` is iterating over the dictionary, but by default, you [iterate over the keys](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) only:

> **iter(d)**
>
> Return an iterator **over the keys** of the dictionary. This is a shortcut for iterkeys().

What you probably want is either [items()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) or [values()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values).

> **items()**
>
> Return a copy of the dictionary’s list of **(key, value) pairs**.
>
> **values()**
>
> Return a copy of the dictionary’s **list of values**. See the note for dict.items().

I think you want this:

```
for name, score in players.items():
      print name, " : ", score
```

Or maybe:

```
for index, (name, score) in enumerate(players.items()):
      print index, " : ", name, " : ", score
```

Just to demonstrate the other two possibilities, this method looks up all of the names:

```
for name in players: # or players.keys()
    print name
```

And this looks up scores (without names):

```
for score in players.values():
    print score
```

Answer (score 2):

The enumerate method gives back index, value pairs. It appears that for a dictionary enumerate is enumerating the key collection (which is why you see the keys).

Answer (score 2):

In here,

```
for value, index in enumerate(players): 
    print index, " : ", value
```

`value` is the counter of enumerate, that is why you're always going to see `value` goes from 0,1,2,3,...

I think what you really wanted is

```
for index, value in enumerate(players): 
    print value, " : ", players[value] # .get works as well
```

Enumerating dictionary generally makes little sense because dictionary are unordered.